# How to show unique records in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

There is a model named Company and it is having number of records. Later I added a field named area. I search field, i am adding this field too.

I am displaying all the areas in a drop down as follows:

```
<%= label_tag :area, "Area" %>
<%= select_tag 'area', options_for_select(Company.uniq.pluck(:area)),include_blank: true, class: 'form-control'} %>
```

Now areas are displaying fine but when I give area as "us" in one case and "US" in another case and "Us" in other case, it is displaying 3 fields 
and also the previous records will be having area fields as empty/blank, here it is showing 2 or more blanks.

How to show unique records for capital and downcase and how to show only one blank in drop down?

Comment: So you want to show only one `US`? instead of `Us`, `US` and `us` or something else?

Comment: Yes. I want to show anyone of the above including one blank field in drop down (instead of 2 or more)

Comment: okay, then try my answer. That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
Company.uniq.pluck(:area)
```

to this:

```
Company.pluck(:area).compact.map(&:downcase).uniq
```

This will give you uniq downcased areas. i.e. you will get only `us` instead of three options: `US`, `us` and `Us`.

Comment: **undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass** Iis the error i am getting

Comment: Did you try this: `Company.pluck(:area).compact.map(&:downcase).uniq`? Let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: Awesome! :) Great to hear :)